# Deploying a qt application on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I have read and followed the procedure given on [qt website](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html). But I am unsuccessful in deploying my application (on ubuntu 15.10, qt 5.4). I followed many blogs and answers on stackoverflow in vain. (In particular, I [tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21700394/2190313))

I downloaded the qt source and built it statically. But I am unable to deploy my application. My application uses "webkit". So I manually built the webkit and webkitwidgets. Then I configured my Qt creator to use the static build of qtversion for building my app. It throws an error

```
Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwigets
```

But I rechecked that webkit and webkitwidgets have been built statically. So, where am I going wrong?

Alternatively, I tried the [statifier application](http://statifier.sourceforge.net/), but it always produces a corrupt executable that does not even run on the same system. (Ermine - commercial version of statifier is not an option for me)

How do I deploy this app on linux?

Comment: Are you able to do a normal deployment by linking dynamically to the Qt that OS has?

Comment: @Velkan , yes, I am able to deploy it dynamically

Comment: @clearScreen so why not deploy it dynamically? You can even create a deb (or rpm, or other package format) with all the correct dependencies...